# error: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to make a calculator in flutter for the first time, but an error occur at the bool type that i don't understand. (on the "if" opertaion)

```
class _CalculatorAppState extends State<CalculatorApp> {
  int? firstNum;
  int? secondnum;
  String? textToDisplay;
  String? history = '';
  String? res = '';
  String? operation;

  void btnOnClick(String btnVal){
    print(btnVal);
    if( btnVal == 'C'){
      textToDisplay = '';
      firstNum = 0;
      secondnum = 0;
      res= '';
    } else if (btnVal == 'C'){
      textToDisplay = '';
      firstNum = 0;
      secondnum = 0;
      res= '';
      history = '';
    } else if ( btnVal == '+'||
        btnVal == '-'||
        btnVal == '/'||
        btnVal == 'X') {
      firstNum = int.parse(textToDisplay!);
      res = '';
      operation = btnVal;
    } else if (btnVal == '='){
      secondnum = int.parse(textToDisplay!);
      if(operation = '+') {
        res = (firstNum! + secondnum!).toString();
        history = firstNum.toString() + operation.toString() + secondnum.toString();
      }
      if(operation = '-') {
        res = (firstNum! - secondnum!).toString();
        history = firstNum.toString() + operation.toString() + secondnum.toString();
      }
      if(operation = 'X') {
        res = (firstNum! * secondnum!).toString();
        history = firstNum.toString() + operation.toString() + secondnum.toString();
      }
      if(operation = '/') {
        res = (firstNum! / secondnum!).toString();
        history = firstNum.toString() + operation.toString() + secondnum.toString();
      } else {
        res = int.parse(textToDisplay! + btnVal).toString();
      }

      setState(() {
        textToDisplay = res;
      });
    }
  }
```

error: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. (non_bool_condition at [calculator] lib\main.dart:46)

error: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. (non_bool_condition at [calculator] lib\main.dart:50)

error: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. (non_bool_condition at [calculator] lib\main.dart:54)

error: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. (non_bool_condition at [calculator] lib\main.dart:58)

Answer (score 2):

You're currently typing `operation = 'x'` which isnt valid syntax. You need a double '=', so:

```dart
if (operation == 'x') {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator is `==` not `=`.

At those lines listed you used `=` instead of `==`.

And declare the variables as follows:

```
var firstNum = 0;
var secondnum = 0;
var textToDisplay = '';
var history = '';
var res = '';
var operation = '';
```

Comment: I tried it and it says:

Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: Because you declared all variables as nullable. You should try not to use nuulable variables unless there is no choice. In your case use `if operation! == 'X') ...`